# With OWA set to fr-CA, Office.context.displayLanguage returns en-US

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

If I set the language in OWA to "French (Canada)" in *Region and time zone settings* then Office.context.displayLanguage() returns en-US instead of fr-CA.

I get the correct result for the language set to the other French choices available in OWA:

1. fr-FR
2. fr-LU
3. fr-BE
4. fr-MC
5. fr-CH

Did anyone else see this result? I suspect it is a bug with the Office.js code but it might be something to do with OWA or something I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for reporting.  I can repro this issue as well and we are following up.  I notice that in my repro, when the user chooses fr-CA, in addition to the API returning en-US, the regular buttons in OWA are also displayed in English instead of in French.  Is that what you see as well?

Comment: @OutlookWebAddinsTeam I can confirm your observation. Even more, I switch to French and right now don't have any more "language and region settings" section anymore. Cannot switch back to English. Entire interface is displayed partially in French and partially in English.

Comment: With OWA set to fr-CA the waffle buttons (Mail, Calendar, etc.) are in English, but the interfaces within the Mail view, etc. are all in French. In addition my add-in's add-in commands are all in French. Note that in order to get the add-in commands to show in French

Comment: ...for both Outlook 2016 I had to use two Override entries in my manifest: since setting the display to French on Outlook 2016 corresponds to fr-FR in Outlook, I needed an fr-fr Override entry for that. But for OWA you choose the specific language + culture (fr-FR, fr-CA, etc.) so instead of having an Override in the manifest for all combinations, I discovered that an extra Override entry with just "fr" worked for all of those as a catch-all.

Comment: @Carbo - Can you still repro the issue?

Comment: It is fixed now. Thanks!